# Watersheds tool does not create watersheds in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, hydrology, watershed

I`m trying to create watersheds and every time I run the Watershed tool, the result will be very interesting.

I use snap raster and I set the extent of the output to the extent of the flow direction raster, but it does not make any difference.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

[image: So this is how the watersheds look like]
[image: This is how it should look like]

Comment: I`m using the flow direction raster.

Answer (score 1):

The screen capture you included looks to be correct if your parameter was in fact pour points (as oppose to a stream link raster); each pour point generated a contributing watershed basin.

If you want to run the a continuous watershed model across the region then you should use the stream link raster as your second parameter in the Watershed tool.  To create the Stream Links raster you first need to delineate a stream network of cells with highest accumulation; I use the Raster Calculator and SetNull function:  `SetNull("flow_acc"<100000,1)` for example

Once you have the Stream Raster; this becomes the input into the Stream Link tool. The output from the stream link tool is what you use as the input into the Watershed tool "Input Raster or Feature Pour Point data" parameter.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I inserted an image of the expected output in the question above.I have run this tool before with the same pour point and it worked fine.

Comment: Yes the second capture shows exactly what you will get when you use stream links.  Pour point only generates a contributing basin for that point; if you have enough points and clean, hydrologically correct, data and your points are all snapped then I suppose you could have theoretically created something like what your second capture depicts, however it is more commonly done with stream links.

Comment: I just have run the Stream Link tool and it has generated a network, but not the watersheds

Comment: As I said, you use the output from the Stream Link tool as the input into the watershed tool's "Input raster or feature point data" as indicated by an arrow in my second screen capture.